# Adding Rational Expressions

Tags: rational-numbers

$$\frac{7a}{6a^2-15a} + \frac{12a}{4a^2-25}$$

I determined the LCD of the denominators: $(3a)(2a-5)(2a+5)$. I then multiplied all nominators by the LCM, combined the terms and got:

$$\frac{a(86a+95)}{(3a)(2a-5)(2a+5)}$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What happened to the $a$ in the denominator?  Note:  you can reduce the first fraction by cancelling a factor of $a$ .

Comment: You went wrong somewhere in the part that you haven't shown: "*Multiply everything by LCM*". That should rather be:

$$\require{cancel}
\frac{7 \cancel{a}}{3\cancel{a}(2a-5)} + \frac{12a}{(2a-5)(2a+5)}=\frac{7 \cdot (2a+5)+12a\cdot 3}{3(2a-5)(2a+5)}$$

Comment: somewhere between the first line and the last line. But you don't show us no "between" lines, so how can we point at the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{7a}{6a^2-15a} + \frac{12a}{4a^2-25} = \frac{7}{3(2a-5)} + \frac{12a}{(2a-5)(2a+5)} = \frac{7(2a+5) + 12a3}{3(2a-5)(2a+5)} = \frac{50a+35}{3(2a-5)(2a+5)} = \frac{5(10a+7)}{3(2a-5)(2a+5)}$$