# Subtracting Rational Expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers

$$
\frac{3a+2}{36-a^2} - \frac{a-4}{a^2-8a+12}
$$

Got stuck on this equation. 
$$
\frac{3a+2}{(6-a)(6+a)} - \frac{a-4}{(a-6)(a-2)}
$$

For this part, what do I do about the $(6-a)(6+a)$? Do I take away a $-1$ or something else?

Edit: I think I figured out the answer, thanks to all of your help. 
[image]

Comment: You will want to combine both fractions under a common denominator.  What do you think this denominator would be?  Hint: you need three factors multiplied together.

Comment: Between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320174/adding-rational-expressions) it looks like you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.  What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Sorry. I finished the majority of my homework and just had three questionsI was stuck on. I think I might have to flip the second fraction just like I would if I had to divide? I also think I might have to take a -1 out of the first fraction in order to make the denominator easier to manage? But I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
-\frac{a-4}{(a-6)(a-2)}=+\frac{a-4}{(6-a)(a-2)}
$$

Comment: Thanks. I think I figured out the answer.
[IMG]http://i66.tinypic.com/rws7b5.png[/IMG]

Edit: Sorry, I don't know how to post photos in comments.

Comment: OK ! The result is correct.  To learn how to write math formulas, study this:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.. And don't forget to accept a question when it is good for you.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Note that $-(a-6) = 6-a$, so
$$
\frac{3a+2}{(6-a)(6+a)} - \frac{a-4}{(a-6)(a-2)}
 = \frac{1}{6-a} \left[ \frac{3a+2}{6+a} + \frac{a-4}{a-2}\right]
$$
and now just bring the fractions inside the bracket to a common denominator.